# How do i check whether my current navigationController.view = a classes.view? Reason = push notifications. + iphone

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

so basically in my app delegate  i have a navigation.controller

This navigation controller has a view of a class named MainScreen.

In MainScreen.m , i have a IBAction which will bring me to a SelectionScreen.m page by pushing it. here is the coding for it

```
SelectionScreen *aSelectionScreenViewController = [[SelectionScreen alloc]initWithNibName:@"SelectionScreen" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:aSelectionScreenViewController animated:YES];
[aSelectionScreenViewController release];
```

So how do i check if my current navigationController.view = this selectionscreen.view?

The reason for checking which current view it is, is because when i receieve a push notification, i would want to automatically switch to this SelectionScreen.m page and invoke some methods within it. But this checking can only be done in the appDelegate because the didReceiveRemoteNotification method is located in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys, i did it in a simple way. In every view controller i had, i removed all objects and assigned an object to an array in the appdelegate. So this way, everytime i go to a new view, the value is different.

So in appdidrecieveremotenotification, i can check that array and decide on what to do accordingly.

Its just a simple way of checking.

Answer (score 8):

This is how i'm doing it

for example if you have three ViewControllers ,and any of those have possibility to be pushed by NavigationController:

```
ViewControllerA
ViewControllerB
ViewControllerC
```

Then what you need to do is:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    if ([[self.navigationController topViewController] isKindOfClass:[ViewControllerA class]]) {

    //do sth
    }

    if ([[self.navigationController topViewController] isKindOfClass:[ViewControllerB class]]) {

    //do sth
    }

    if ([[self.navigationController topViewController] isKindOfClass:[ViewControllerC class]]) {

    //do sth
    }

}//end of code
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to save selectionScreenViewController as a property of your app delegate, then:

```
if (self.navigationController.topViewController == self.selectionScreenViewController) {
   //...
}
else {
   //...
}
```

Comment: Sorry i dun know how to do that :\ .